# Why do Facebook, Twitter and GMail render all their data to the browser as JSON as opposed to HTML?

Tags: html, ajax, json, twitter, gmail

If you login to Facebook, Twitter or Gmail and view source, you'll notice something very peculiar. All your Tweets and mail are rendered as JSON. There are no angle brackets. My guess is, this data is all dynamically rendered to the DOM. If you inspect any element on the page, you'll see tons of divs and other HTML elements. None of which was served in the original markup. The questions are:

1. Why would these 3 huge sites take time out to do this?
2. Wouldn't it be faster to just use HTML?
3. Is it to save on bandwidth since the JSON payload is smaller to serve than HTML?
4. Is it because these sites are heavily based on AJAX? My guess would be the former, but I have no idea. I'm not sure if you have to work for Google Twitter, or Facebook to know why this is, but this tactic is shared between the 3 sites, so I figure they have a common goal in mind. That makes me think it's more of a general thing.

Comment: I've just discovered the same thing on Facebook guys. So I added it to the list. Thanks guys!!

Comment: I recently discovered this is the concept of a Single Page Application. These apps typically don't refresh the page, have lots of events being triggered (new email, new tweet, new message, etc)., and interact heavily with the server through polling or persistent connections. Backbone.js is a good framework for such a task and has received a lot of buzz and attention lately as a result.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several reasons for their design that are commonly applied:

1. As the previous answers mentioned, caching can be utilized in the browser and JSON payload is lighter
2. They are providing a clean separation between the service, the UI logic and data following the MVC pattern

   - JSON as a Model
   - JavaScript UI Widget as View that renders the data
   - Service layer as the Controller that provides the business logic/service that feeds into the UI  Layer
3. API driven architecture and separation mentioned in point #2 above allow the company to provide multiple channels delivery without too much rework. Consider if we want to build Twitter App for Android:

   - JSON as Model stays the same, nothing needs to be rework here as the data is the same
   - We now will change the View from HTML to Android Native UI, in this case we will need to code the UI layer code
   - Service Layer as Controller remains the same and we dont' have to do anything here

   As you can see, this model provides a way for Google/Twitter to deliver into multi-channels without having to rewrite their logic. The same applies to Mobile WebView vs. normal Desktop WebView. All we need to change is the UI Layer and not the Data or Controller layer.

This is why they are taking time to think about the design and architecture it as such. A tight coupling between the data and presentation would require them to rework a lot of code in order to be delivered in multiple channels. It's not about JSON vs. HTML or just the web but more of an architecture decision that would allow them to deliver their content to multi-channels (iOS, Android, third party App, Mobile WebView, Desktop View, Desktop App, etc). What you see in their HTML source is the manifestation of their strategy in WebView channel.

Answer (score 3):

This technique allows the browser to cache the HTML(and static javascripts) and only fetch a json string. It is quite fast indeed and bandwith friendly.

Comment: JSON data is still part of the initial response, this does not improve caching. (They are not serving a static file.)

Comment: Well...it is indeed possible to cache a specific portion of a page. I've seen this technique with "Donut Caching". http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/11/28/tip-trick-implement-donut-caching-with-the-asp-net-2-0-output-cache-substitution-feature.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

No it wouldn't be faster. JSON is a lot easier to generate on the server side than HTML. As far as I know Twitter also uses [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) for rendering these data on the client.

So you just serve the static templates (if cached properly they only need to be loaded once) and your JSON data and then let the client do all the rendering work. One advantage is, that the client can pick what and how they want to render the data and another that it takes all the heavy HTML generation overhead from the servers.

Answer (score 0):

My guess: to avoid repeating UI related code.

I just took a look at Twitter's source code, and it seems like they wanted to keep all UI logic in JavaScript. This is reasonable since Twitter page will keep fetching new tweets, so they had to write UI related code in JavaScript anyway. So, rather than repeating the same code in the backend, it is just seeding the initial data to render the tweets at the time of page load with JavaScript.

Caching arguments do not make sense to me, since it will work the same way in either approach since the initial page request is not cacheable.

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is a separation of presentation and data taken to another level. There is a layer on the server side which just provides data. In general, JSON is a good way to provide that data. Now how you present it can be treated separately.

This JSON can be delivered via web services to any interested client (Web/Desktop/Mobile/Other API). Then the client can decide how to present it. On Web we use lot of javascripts to read and parse this JSON and manipulate the screen/DOM .